# Cannot open url. please check this url is correct

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm developing a very simple Java web app with Tomcat (Maven Project) in Intellij (Version 14.0.3).

When I compile and deploy the package (command: "`mvn clean package`: using Intellij) and then run the program 
I get a popup saying :

> ```
> Cannot open url. Please check this url is correct.
> ```

The URL is "`http://localhost:8080/TimeDisplay/ShowTime.html`".

Needless to say, when I try accessing this URL directly through the browser I get to the page I created.

Here are the relevant fields of the project's Run Configuration:

- **Application Server**: Tomcat 9.0.0.M3
- **Open browser**: After launch checked with Firefox as the chosen browser. The link is the same as the one I get in the error.
- **On 'Update' action**: Restart server
- **On frame deactivation**: Do nothing
- **Tomcat Server Settings**:
- **HTTP port**: 8080
- **JMX port**: 1099

Under the deployment tab I added "TimeDisplay:war exploded" (*TimeDisplay is the name of my project*).

My `pom.xml` is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="removed link due to low stackoverflow reputation" xmlns:xsi="removed link due to low stackoverflow reputation"
 xsi:schemaLocation="removed link due to low stackoverflow reputation">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.amin</groupId>
  <artifactId>TimeDisplay</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TimeDisplay Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>TimeDisplay</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I'm also attaching a screenshot of my project's structure.

[image: Project Structure]

It's worth noting that I was able to run the program through Intellij at first and this issue suddenly popped out without any changes done by me. Currently I'm packaging my code and manually deploying it in Tomcat, which is horrendous!

Comment: Is the Tomcat service running when you start debugging your app in IntelliJ?

Comment: @LukeWoodward yes. Running the project also starts (Or restarts) the Tomcat service. As soon as I get the mentioned popup I go and check the availability of the link, and find that it is actually up.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to ask was whether the 'Apache Tomcat' service was running in the Services dialog (it looks like you're using Windows, please correct me if I'm wrong).  The Windows service needs to be stopped for debugging web apps with Tomcat in IntelliJ to work: IntelliJ starts up its own copy of Tomcat, but if the Windows service is running, and hence using port 8080, IntelliJ's copy of Tomcat won't be able to use that port.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I am using Windows as you said, but the Tomcat is not running as standalone when this issue happens, only through IntelliJ. When Tomcat was running by itself I wasn't able to run my program through IntelliJ at all since, as you said, their would be a port conflict. I would get some port listener exception.

Comment: The only other suggestion I have is that if your app is doing an HTTP -> HTTPS redirect (e.g. due to `transport-guarantee` set to `CONFIDENTIAL` in web.xml) then you may see this error.

Comment: Same issue when updating to 2024.1 Beta (didn't see it was a beta when clicking without looking at version on Update in JetBrains Toolbox) where a Tomcat service that was working felt in this issue, it worked back tolling back to 2023.3.5 version.

Answer (score 6):

There are probably more reasons for not displaying the web page in the external web browser. In my case the problem is the way Idea is trying to detect the application is deployed.

My web application uses single sign on and when the request is being made with no authentication, the application redirects the user to the external site to log in. However IntelliJ Idea is probably trying to wait for 200 response and spams my application with numerous requests. Correct response of the application is 302 for unauthenticated user though. And when it does not happen in some specific time frame, Idea complains about not being able to display the page and it will not even try to open the browser.

Comment: It seems you are correct, does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Ok I solved the issue. It seems that there is a bug in IntelliJ 14.0.3. I removed my Run Configuration and created it again with the same parameters, and it started working immediately. So as a workaround, recreating the configuration solves the issue.